# How to group bookmarks in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I would like to group my bookmarks like buffers with ibuffer or newsgroups with gnus by certain criterias like projects for example. I also tried Bookmark+ but couldn't get anything like this working.
Does anyone know a way to achive this?

Answer (score 6):

[**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) provides several different ways of grouping, organizing, and even combining bookmarks.  ("Grouping" can mean several different things.)

Take a look at these possibilities:

- Using [multiple bookmark lists](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#UsingMultipleBookmarkLists) (i.e., bookmark-list views);
- Using [multiple bookmark files](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#UsingMultipleBookmarkFiles);
- Bookmarking a bookmark list itself or a bookmark file itself or a Dired buffer with its markings etc.;
- [Tagging](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) bookmarks

What problems did you run into trying to use it to group bookmarks?  What did you try, for instance?

Comment: In my first pass with `bookmarks`, I used multiple bookmark files. But to keep it simpler (too much "out of sight, out of mind"), I'm going to try to lean towards the `tags` approach this time. I do wish Emacs' grouping of `bookmarks` was a bit more visually transparent, as the OP is looking for.

Comment: You mention multiple bookmark **files**. That is one way. I mentioned multiple bookmark **lists**, which is not the same thing.  Both are possible and provide different benefits. I also mentioned Bookmark+ **tags**, which provide yet another way to group bookmarks.  All of these ways can be combined.

Comment: Ah, good point (altogether your post). Thank you for clarifying, so with tags and lists, we could possibly have intersecting groups... I will have to try the lists soon. Bookmarking the list -as you point out- would make it more GUI like. The `bookmark+` documentation is a dense read!

Comment: @BradyTrainor 1. By bookmark lists I mean bookmark display lists, i.e., different states of buffer `*Bookmark List*`.  You can make a bookmark of each such state. Such a stated records a given set of bookmarks, but also their markings, omissions, etc. 2. Tags alone give you easy set intersections. And you can in effect save different tag combinations using bookmark-list bookmarks.

Comment: OK, should be fixed now (took me a moment to understand what links and what numbers you were talking about).